# How do I use global namespace type hinting inside of a namespaced class in PHP 5.3+?

Tags: php, namespaces

```
namespace MyClass\Util;

class Sample {

  public function each(Object $f) {

  }
}
```

---

From Calling File (not namespaced)

```
$sample = new Sample();
$sample->each(new stdClass());
```

Produces:

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to MyClass\Util\Sample.php must be an instance of MyClass\Util\Object, instance of Object given

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\` to point to the global namespace :

```
namespace MyClass\Util;

class Sample {

  public function each(\Object $f) {

  }
}
```

As a reference, you can read [**Global space**](http://php.net/language.namespaces.global) *(quoting)* :

> Prefixing a name with `\` will specify
>   that the name is required from the
>   global space even in the context of
>   the namespace.