# Extending un-namespaced class from a namespace

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I have the following legacy file (can't edit):

```
class Test {
    public $abc=1;
}
```

I need to extend this class from a name-spaced file:

```
use mynamespace;
class MyClass extends Test {
}
```

However my auto-load function attempts to include mynamespace\Test. How to specify that un-namespaced version of Test should be used?

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625303/how-do-i-use-global-namespace-type-hinting-inside-of-a-namespaced-class-in-php-5/5625334#5625334) to a related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix the class name with a `\`:

```
class MyClass extends \Test {
    ...
}
```

From the [manual on namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php): "Note that to access any global class, function or constant, a fully qualified name can be used, such as `\strlen()` or `\Exception` or `\INI_ALL`."

Comment: It works! I'm pretty sure I have tried that before but something was wrong. Maybe I made mistake somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class MyClass extends \Test {
}
```